# Integrating 2 Wordpress sites inro one Salesforce CRM

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I am trying to integrate two Wordpress sites that create leads into one Wordpress system. The problem is that the leads ids are auto incremented in these two sites, so that there are duplicated ids that are entered into Salesforce.

We have two commercial sites that once you subscribe to one of them, a lead is created in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Change the integration from Wordpress to Salesforce so that a unique lead ID is generated when you import a lead into Salesforce. It can be as simple as appending the name of the site where lead came from.

Wordpress site A, lead id 123 -> import to Salesforce -> lead id in Salesforce is 123-A
Wordpress site B, lead id 123 -> import to Salesforce -> lead id in Salesforce is 123-B